# Murphy dresser door with flushed rear

Tags: doors

I am planning to install a murphy door between my office room and kitchen. The passage is 36 by 80. I don't want to setup a normal door since I want to use the space for cabinets. The cabinets should be in the office room and the rear of door should be in kitchen.

The catch is the door should not protrude on the rear, i.e. kitchen. It should rather protrude in the front, i.e. office room. How do I order something like this? Or is there a better and cheaper way to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Specify *surface-mount*, like these *Surface-Mount Bi-Fold Cabinet Doors*:

[image]

[Murphy Door](https://murphydoor.com/products/bi-folding-surface-mount-door)